# ASP.Net get the domain name not the localhost?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dns

I'm trying to write a method which will send an email to client which has a download link that the user can click on to download directly.

Actually I'm emulating it as a continuously running process in Global which keep sending a file to a ftp server, if there is an error with the sending, a link will be sent to admin so that he can download the file directly.

My question is how can I get the external link, for example I would like to have http://www.abc.com/temp/file.txt. I want a generic solution so that whatever the domain I change my server too, the code still work?

Thanks

Comment: How does this service relate to the server?

Comment: it's a part of the server? actually I'm emulating it as a continuously running service in Global which keep sending a file to a ftp server, if there is an error with the sending, a link will be sent to admin to download the file directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET doesn't technically "know" what the entry domains are. All it cares about are *applications*, which are mostly orthogonal to the authority the user is coming in on. In the context of a request thread, it knows which domain that user probably asked for, but that's all.

You can get the server-relative path by using (among other things) [`Control.ResolveUrl("~/path_to_file");`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) - from there, you'll need some config-driven way of determining what the domain should be.

Comment: so this means there is absolutely no other way besides reading from config file or getting it from user Request?

Comment: @Kenny or reading the configured host header domains out of the IIS metabase and somehow picking the right one from that. Config sounds easier to me :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I understand question fully, but on IIS 7 you can get domains (IIS Bindings) defined for some site with Microsoft.Web.Administration assembly

```
ServerManager sman = new ServerManager();     
foreach (Site iisSite in sman.Sites)
{
  foreach (Binding bind in iisSite.Bindings)
  {
    // bind.Host - here is the site domain
  }

}
```